# Optional OrderBy parameter in MySql Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm being passed in an optional OrderBy value that should default to `DESC`, and if set to false, should `ORDER BY ASC`. I'm not really sure how to do this ordering based off the input. Here is what I have currently:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`app`@`%` PROCEDURE `BLAH`(
pWithdrawalTransactionId INT,
pLimit INT,
pSortDescending TINYINT
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE vLimit INT DEFAULT COALESCE(pLimit, 100);
    DECLARE vSort TINYINT DEFAULT COALESCE(pSortDescending, 1);

    SELECT
        f.WithdrawalFulfillmentId, f.PaymentStatusId, f.PaymentProcessorId, f.PaymentTypeId, r.Amount, r.RequestedAmount, r.NativeAmount, r.NativeRequestedAmount, r.RefundTransactionId, r.UpdatedDate
    FROM
        FinOps.UserWithdrawalFulfillment f
    INNER JOIN 
        FinOps.UserRefundTransaction r ON f.RefundTransactionId = r.RefundTransactionId
    WHERE
        f.WithdrawalTransactionId = pWithdrawalTransactionId
    LIMIT
        vLimit;
END
```

Comment: It depends on what column(-type) you want to order by and if you need your indexes to work with the ordering (e.g. if you have a composite index that includes `WithdrawalTransactionId` or `RefundTransactionIdand` and your ordering column)

Comment: I would want to order by the WithdrawalTransactionId, if that helps. But the real struggle is the optional part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the correct way to do this would be like this:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`app`@`%` PROCEDURE `BLAH`(
pWithdrawalTransactionId INT,
pLimit INT,
pSortDescending TINYINT
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE vLimit INT DEFAULT COALESCE(pLimit, 100);
    DECLARE vSort TINYINT DEFAULT COALESCE(pSortDescending, 1);

    SELECT
        f.WithdrawalFulfillmentId, f.PaymentStatusId, f.PaymentProcessorId, f.PaymentTypeId, r.Amount, r.RequestedAmount, r.NativeAmount, r.NativeRequestedAmount, r.RefundTransactionId, r.UpdatedDate
    FROM
        FinOps.UserWithdrawalFulfillment f
    INNER JOIN 
        FinOps.UserRefundTransaction r ON f.RefundTransactionId = r.RefundTransactionId
    WHERE
        f.WithdrawalTransactionId = pWithdrawalTransactionId
    ORDER BY CASE WHEN pSortDescending = 1 THEN WithdrawalFulfillmentId * -1 ELSE WithdrawalFulfillmentId END ASC
    LIMIT
        vLimit;
END
```